# How to record and play back randoms in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, random

I am working on an application which includes a generation phase where a set of data is generated. The generation involves a number of loops, some of which generate random numbers in order to make decisions of how to proceed. This means the generated set of data is not the same every time. At the moment, all the random numbers are generated based on individual `Random` objects with each one being constructed with the no-arg `Random()` constructor.

I am trying to track down some bugs which occur only under specific conditions with the set of generated data. Given a buggy dataset, I know why the bugs occur in the application, but what I'm trying to troubleshoot is how the generation phase got to generate the buggy dataset in the first place. However this is not easy to debug because 99% of the time the generation phase does not generate a buggy dataset.

Due to this, I wanted to have a way to record and playback the numbers which are being generated, to reproduce the specific conditions under which the bugs occur. I have searched for such a framework online but I have not come up with anything. Unfortunately "record randoms" returns mostly results about random records, whereas "repeatable randoms" returns mostly results about non-repeatable RNGs!

I know that the code in the generation phase only ever calls the `java.util.Random.nextInt(int)` method which simplifies the problem somewhat. I started to think about creating a repeatable random framework myself.

```
public class RepeatableRandom extends Random {
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private static enum Mode { PASSTHROUGH, RECORD, PLAYBACK; }
    private static Mode mode = Mode.PASSTHROUGH;
    // ...synchronized setters for each of the three modes...

    private static Map<Integer,Integer> invocationCount = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<Integer,List<Integer>> randoms = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public int nextInt(int n) {
        switch (mode) {
            case Mode.PASSTHROUGH:
                return RANDOM.nextInt(n);
            case Mode.RECORD:
                if (!randoms.containsKey(n)) {
                    randoms.put(n,new ArrayList<>());
                }
                int nextInt = RANDOM.nextInt(n);
                randoms.get(n).put(nextInt);
                return nextInt;
            case Mode.PLAYBACK:
                synchronized(LOCK) {
                    int i = invocationCount.get(n);
                    int nextInt = randoms.get(n).get(invocationCount);
                    invocationCount.put(n,i+1);
                    return nextInt;
                }
        }
    }

    public void loadRandomsFromFile(String filename) { //... }
    public void saveRandomsToFile(String filename) { //... }
    public void clear() { // ... }
}
```

After replacing all references to `Random` in the generation phase with `RepeatableRandom` I then would write test code like the following:

```
RepeatableRandom.setRecordMode();
do {
    RepeatableRandom.clear();
    dataSet = generateDataSet();
while (!isBuggyDataSet(dataSet));
RepeatableRandom.saveRandomsToFile(FILENAME);
```

Later, in my code I can then write:

```
RepeatableRandom.setPlaybackMode();
RepeatableRandom.clear();
RepeatableRandom.loadRandomsFromFile(FILENAME);
executeMainApplication();
```

I can then run in debug mode with a load of breakpoints and finally figure out why this specific buggy set of data is generated.

However I feel sure I am not the first person to have faced this problem. And I don't feel comfortable with creating a whole new bespoke framework just for this use case. I feel there must be something already out there but I just can't find it! What is the correct approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I am curious in that I see no mention of consideration of the Random class's *seed* anywhere in your post above. Maybe I'm misreading your question and misunderstanding your problem, but isn't this the way to get repeatable progression from the Random class? Save the *seed*, and re-use it if desired?

Comment: The code currently calls the no-argument constructor of `Random`. AFAIK there is no way to get the seed which is used inside `Random` after construction. Is `new Random()` equivalent to `new Random((new Random()).nextLong());`?

Comment: No, I believe that Random gets its random seed from the system clock, but I could be wrong. But why even worry about this? Why not set the seed yourself using the constructor that takes a long?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's exactly what I meant. However in the normal (non-debugging) case, we would want to set the value of that long to itself be a random number. In order to not disturb the current behaviour of the application being debugged, I was just asking whether this is the same as what it does when you call the no-args constructor. Also, I've just realised another problem with this approach - the code constructs lots of `Random` objects, not only one, and so in order to ensure the same first random doesn't get generated every time, one would have to track a whole series of seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple Random objects, then in your test code you can set up a single Master Random with a known seed. Use that Master to provide seeds for the other Child Random instances. By repeating the seed for the Master, all the other Child instances will get whatever seed they got the last time that master seed was used provided they start in the same order.

If you don't want to repeat then just seed the Master from the clock or whatever.

Comment: I think that is the best approach - even though the exact seeds used will now be different (as each seed will be based on the output of the master `Random` rather than the system clock at that time), it should not affect the overall pseudorandom behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot of code...

Do you realise that you can always start a random sequence from the same place, using a seed? When you create a new Random you can pass in a seed value, and if you use the same seed twice then the numbers you generate will be identical each time.

Pick a seed, run your tests, and if they don't show the behaviour you're after then increment the seed and try again. When you get what you're looking for, make a note of the seed and always use that number from then on.

Comment: There are multiple `Random` objects constructed. If we used the same seed for all of them, the behaviour of the application would be fundamentally changed because the first integer produced would always be the same for each of the `Random` objects (and the second, etc)

Comment: If you have multiple `Random` objects, then in your test code set up a single master `Random` with a known seed.  Use that master to provide seeds for the other `Random` instances.  By repeating the seed for the master, all the other instances will get whatever seed they got the last time that master seed was used.

Answer (score -1):

Capture the random seed when you begin, and reset it to the same seed during your tests. You may want to change your code to rely on a global Random provider, then you can attach this kind of policy to the application globally.

Comment: You can't capture a random seed